# Why amplitude of tsunami increases as it tavels ashore?

Tags: waves, wavelength, tsunami

I read that there is a displacement between 2 (oceanic) tectonic plate and this drop cause a big potential energy on the wave directly above, I don't buy it because obviously many video footages showed the amplitude of the tsunami gradually becomes bigger as it moves towards the shore? What's going on where do the energy come from?

Comment: Where did you read what you are talking about? I don't understand your explanation of potential energy and plates. The obvious answer is that the amplitude stays the same, but the ground rises up (from the ocean floor to sea level) and so the water goes from a small surface wave to a giant wall. The amplitude is similar, but now all of it is "above the ground" rather than under water where we can't see it.

Comment: @tpg2114: [Link] (https://www.zmescience.com/science/geology/how-tsunamis-form/) I'm re-reading it.

Comment: In deep water, tectonic activity can move many kilotons of water, all the way to the surface, producing a huge amount of kinetic energy.

Comment: It's a good thing that tsunamis don't conserve energy. They lose energy instead of conserving it. if they did conserve energy, the waves would be tens of kilometers tall as they approached land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why amplitude of tsunami increases as it travels ashore?

The energy for the tsunami is given by  "a displacement between 2 (oceanic) tectonic plates", this happens at  depth and the energy is carried by the whole column of water, from surface to bottom of the sea at the point of the displacement.

As the distortion travels to shallower waters, that energy is expressed with a higher amplitude of the tsunami wave.  [See this for example](http://itic.ioc-unesco.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1164&Itemid=2031) :

[image: tsunami]

It is conservation of energy and fluid dynamics after all.